# Is it in the Function Scope or Block Scope?

Tags: javascript

Is my randomNumber variable in my createRandomList function function scoped or block scoped? Is the i variable declaration for my for loop block scoped or function scoped? In all types of loops, if I use the let key to declare a variable (`for(let i = 0; i < something.length; i += 1) {
// something goes in here
}`) within the parentheses section of a for loop, the variable is block scoped, right? One last question, in for loops, the whole statement is the loop, right? The loop isn't only the code block, right? I ask because some people refer to the whole thing as the loop and other people refer the the code block as the loop.

```js
function random100() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

function createRandomList() {
  let arr = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    let randomNumber = random100() ; 
    arr.push(randomNumber) ;
    
  }
  return arr ;
}

/* 
console.log(randomNumber) ; <---- Does this not work because you can't access a variable in the local scope from outside the local scope or because let is block scoped? 
*/ 

let myRandomList = createRandomList() ;

for (let i = 0; i < myRandomList.length; i += 1) {
    console.log("Item " + i + " in the array is " + myRandomList[i] + ".") ;
}
```

Comment: `let` -> block scope.

Comment: @VLAZ yes i know this but in for loops is the let variable declared in the parentheses  `for (let i = 0; i < something.length; i ++ )`  block scoped???? yes right because its read and processed before anything else? and because the last bit of code in the parentheses is run whenever everything in the code block is done running right?

Comment: "*I ask because some people refer to the whole thing as the loop and other people refer the the code block as the loop*" which people and how exactly have they phrased it? Because both of these are possibly correct. The code that will be executed each loop can also be called "loop body" so, when discussing the whole construct, the body might need to be distinguished. The `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)` part can be called loop initialisation or loop statement or something but it's a bit meaningless to separate it from the body.

Comment: In this case it absolutely doesn't matter because `randomNumber` is a **number**, not an object. The function would work the same way if everything were declared with `var`.

Comment: @VLAZ programmers on youtube and i dont really remember there exact i just know that some refer to the the code block connected to the loop initialization as the loop and others refer to the whole statement as the loop. thats why im a little confused.

Comment: @pointy whats stored inside randomNumber is an object. a number is an object.

Comment: @HeavensGate666 that's not exactly correct. The old saying goes "everything in JavaScript is an object" but it's grossly oversimplifying things. What you have stored in `randomNumber` is a numeric primitive. That is *not* an object. You can call stuff like `randomNumber.toString()` but it remains a primitive. When executed, that line will convert the number to a Number object as if it was `new Number(randomNumber).toString()`. But you still have a primitive.

Comment: Numbers are not objects. In JavaScript, strings, numbers, and booleans are *primitives*, not objects.

Comment: @VLAZ i did not know this. I will learn about primitives soon.

Comment: @Pointy ok pointy i didnt mean to disrespect you its just that i was taught that numbers in JS are objects. I will learn about primitives soon.

Comment: @HeavensGate666 oh don't worry about me :)  It *is* confusing, because JavaScript lets you make believe that numbers and strings are objects with very common things like `"foo".length`.  Sure looks like an object, but in fact it's just JavaScript being helpful (and confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my randomNumber variable in my createRandomList function function scoped or block scoped?

Yes.

> Is the i variable declaration for my for loop block scoped or function scoped?

Block scoped to the for loop.

> In for loops, the whole statement is the loop, right?

Yes, kind of. The variable declarations of the `for` are initialized on the block scope (actually EnvironmentRecord) the loops body will be executed in.